# Listening to database events from Java program

Tags: java, database

I have a need like my java program should fetch the record which is recently inserted or updated in the database(preferably Oracle). I have a scenario like there is a home page which displays all the newly inserted records from the database, so how could I know when a new record is inserted into database and how my java process will be notified in such case.
Please help & thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Polling**

Poll the DB at regular intervals for new records.

**Option 2: Push** (My Preference)

Leverage triggers (insert). May be there is a way to send/publish JMS messages from triggers in Oracle. Do a quick search on internet.

Answer (score 0):

you should read about dbms_alert. its an oracle wait/notify style solution.

http://www.oracleutilities.com/Packages/dbms_alert.html

you could have a thread waiting for an "alert", and a db trigger that signal on this alert.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the JDBC change notification:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/java.112/e10589/dbchgnf.htm